# Incrementing int variable through recursion

Tags: python, pointers, recursion

I solved a problem using recursion and incrementing the 0th element in the list `ans` as below:

```
def depthSum(input: list) -> int:
    ans = [0]

    helper(ans, input, 1)

    return ans[0]

def helper(ans: list, input: list, depth: int):
    for element in input:
        if type(element) is list:
            helper(ans, element, depth + 1)
        else:
            ans[0] += depth * element



print(depthSum([[1,1],2,[1,1]]))
print(depthSum([1,[4,[6]]]))
```

However, rather than a list, I was wondering if there was a way to increment an `int` variable and return that as the answer, rather than incrementing the element in an array?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ans` is an integer, you could just return it from `helper`. Returning a value is usually a better alternative to maintaining a reference inside a `list` (or any object).

```
def depthSum(input: list) -> int:
    return helper(input, 1)

def helper(input: list, depth: int):
    ans = 0
    for element in input:
        if type(element) is list:
            ans += helper(element, depth + 1)
        else:
            ans += depth * element
    return ans
```